# negative power on a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a compute a calculus with a negative power on a matrix, however, due of my low math level, I am not sure on how powers and moreover negative ones applies on matrices could you give me some advices ? this calculus is this one: [image]

Comment: That $-1$ means the inverse of the matrix. I hope you know enough about $2 \times 2$ matrices to compute the inverse.

Comment: ho ok. thanks you !

Comment: Yes, $A^{-n}$ is the inverse matrix to $A^n$ or, equivalently, the nth power of $A^{-1}$.  Of course, A must be invertible for that to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a square matrix $A$, $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of A, that exists iff $\det A \ne0$.

For $2\times2$ matrix it is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
d&-b\\-c&a
\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\det A}
$$